Why my streamlines from leaflet-velocity map are going to land?
I try to show currents from Black Sea on a map with streamlines (with leaflet-velocity).
But the map looks bad. Why the currents are show on the land ?
In Version 2, I change dx and dy and VelocityScale.
The map is here: https://syroco.rmri.ro/earth/index.html
I keep the original layer (Ocean Current -Great Barrier Reef) , to see the diference between layers.
I look forward to any suggestion, idea.
My JS code:
function initDemoMap() {
      var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer(
        "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
        {
          attribution:
            "SYROCO 2024" +
            "NIMRD 'Grigore Antipa'"
        }
      );

      var Esri_DarkGreyCanvas = L.tileLayer(
        "http://{s}.sm.mapstack.stamen.com/" +
          "(toner-lite,$fff[difference],$fff[@23],$fff[hsl-saturation@20])/" +
          "{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        {
          attribution:
            "SYROCO 2024" +
            "NIMRD 'Grigore Antipa'"
        }
      );

      var baseLayers = {
        Satellite: Esri_WorldImagery,
        "Grey Canvas": Esri_DarkGreyCanvas
      };

      var map = L.map("map", {
        layers: [Esri_WorldImagery]
      });

      var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers);
      layerControl.addTo(map);
      map.setView([43, 35], 7);

      return {
        map: map,
        layerControl: layerControl
      };
    }

    // demo map
    var mapStuff = initDemoMap();
    var map = mapStuff.map;
    var layerControl = mapStuff.layerControl;

    // load data (u, v grids) from somewhere (e.g. https://github.com/danwild/wind-js-server)
    $.getJSON("water-gbr.json", function(data) {
      var velocityLayer = L.velocityLayer({
        displayValues: true,
        displayOptions: {
          velocityType: "GBR Water",
          position: "bottomleft",
          emptyString: "No water data"
        },
        data: data,
        maxVelocity: 0.6,
        velocityScale: 0.1 // arbitrary default 0.005
      });

      layerControl.addOverlay(velocityLayer, "Ocean Current - Great Barrier Reef");
    });

    //dx=0.15  dy=0.03
    $.getJSON("cuthr_13Dec2024.json", function(data) {
      var velocityLayer = L.velocityLayer({
        displayValues: true,
        displayOptions: {
          velocityType: "GBR Water",
          position: "bottomleft",
          emptyString: "No water data"
        },
        data: data,
        //minVelocity: -0.44,
        maxVelocity: 0.26,
        velocityScale: 0.11 // arbitrary default 0.005
      });

      layerControl.addOverlay(velocityLayer, "Black Sea Current - Version 1");
    });

    // dx=0.09 dy=0.04 
    $.getJSON("cuthr_13Dec2024_8.json", function(data) {
      var velocityLayer = L.velocityLayer({
        displayValues: true,
        displayOptions: {
          velocityType: "GBR Water",
          position: "bottomleft",
          emptyString: "No water data"
        },
        data: data,
        minVelocity: -0.44,
        maxVelocity: 0.3,
        velocityScale: 0.3 // arbitrary default 0.005
      });

      layerControl.addOverlay(velocityLayer, "Black Sea Current - Version 2");
    });

